# how to handle multiple signalr hub in a silverlight LOB application

Tags: silverlight, signalr, signalr-hub

i want to implement SignalR in a silverlight LOB application (using caliburn micro).
The client is composed of many modules dynamicaly loaded by the user.

in a module i can have many active viewmodel, each of them can need to access to different hub.

I did read all the documentations about SignalR (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) but i am still confused about how to use signalr when it's not a single page application.

i understood i can have only one connection in my application so i need to create it in my bootstrapper. i created a service to hold a hubconnection singleton. since i need to create the proxies before to call start() i get from my server the list of all the known hub and create a proxy for each of them. proxies are then stored in a dictionnary to be able to give them to any viewmodel. VM will the share the same proxy instance, is this a problem ?

is this,the way to use signalr in a NO single page application ?

i am not sure of my application design with signalr, so if anyone can share his/her experience about it i will be gratefull

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't create the hub in the first place (that's handled by SignalR), there's no reason to pass an explicit handle from page to page. Whenever you need the hub (that is, when accessing the hub from outside the hub class itself), you can get it like this:

GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext();

Comment: GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContextg() is what I use on the server side. But my concern is about the client side (in my case Silverlight) which is different.